# Patch Asphalt with Plastic

Tags: plastic, asphalt

I have some asphalt I would like to patch.

I stumbled on this product:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXKglt_mkg8

Which is a plastic pellet poured into the pothole and then melted with a torch.

Could I do the same thing with some common household plastic that I could collect and recycle?

if so, what kind of plastic would that be?

Comment: Would probably want to use UV resistant plastic at least, not much sense to do the work if the sun will just break it down.   A way to shred the plastic into small pieces be helpful also.  Google does not seem to list downsides to it yet, but time will tell.

Comment: I would agree with the first comments and add I wonder how many days this holds up. Plastic on a hot day car rolls on it and now it gets stuck in the tire tread , I have seen cheap or not so well prepared garage floor paint peel up on car tires , this stuff??? Home made possibly even worse.

Comment: Having researched it a bit more, it's apparently akin to the stuff they use to paint white/yellow lines on roads. It does last years & it's not as slippy as it first looks. Its primary use is to prevent further break-up due to water ingress & ice. I'd say your chances of DIYing something similar would be about nil… otherwise big business would be coating entire car-parks in recycled Coke bottles & supermarket carriers. The company, of course are saying nothing at all about *exactly* what's in it. Also note it doesn't burst into flames when heated with an industrial road torch.

Comment: Key is that along with various other attributes, plastics melt at different temperatures. While most common plastics won't melt at normal summer temperatures, the temperature under a car that has been driven for an hour can be quite a bit higher.

Comment: With that torch for heat ,you could put down regular asphalt mix. I see Sakrete sells a product.

Answer (score 0):

Had to repair asphalt and there is a 2-pack product that works very well called Renfort.

Mixed and it slowly flows into place, then goes hard.

Comment: Google is not turning up any hits on Renfort.  can you double check the spelling?

Comment: @BeKindToNewUsers so perhaps it no longer exists - seem to be many other products around that are available, even single pack no mix...

Comment: @SolarMike  Is it possible you are remembering the french word renfort on the package, instead of the name.